# Excel - How to sum values for specific days

Tags: excel-formula, sum, weekday

How can I sum all the OT(hr) value only for specific day?
Requirement: I need to sum all the OT(hr) for one person for Sunday only. One person means one row in the table.

I tried this few code but it doesn't work :
=sumif(WEEKDAY(1,1),O8:AD8) or
=SUMIF(O8:AD8,TEXT(O6:AD6,"dddd")="Sunday")

Thank you so much

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my example, I don't use merged cells. I wouldn't recommend having merged cells for the date. Date must be above the OT (hr). And the Ot (hr) you also need to put into the formula.
This formula was working for me:

```
=SUM((WEEKDAY(O2:AD2;1)=1)*(O3:AD3="OT (hr)")*(O4:AD4))
```

[image]